# What are small $(\infty,1)$ categories?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

The term first appeared in Chapter 3 of Lurie's [HTT, p144](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf). Where he says

> The simplicial category $Cat^\Delta_\infty$ has as objects  (small) $\infty$-categories.

What are *small* $\infty$-categories? what are $\kappa$-small $\infty$-categories?

It seems that we first define a universe $U$ for which these "small" objects live in. Then construct the universes $U(\kappa)$ with respect to each **-cardinal.

I am unclear how to make this precise. (i.e. what to put in **).

Comment: Shouldn't it just mean the underlying simplicial set is actually a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lurie mentions in section 1.2.15, he works in the framework of Grothendieck universes for convenience.  In particular, with some inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ fixed in the background, a *small* set (or *$\kappa$-small* set to avoid ambiguity if $\kappa$ might vary) is an element of the Grothendieck universe $U(\kappa)$ of sets of rank less than $\kappa$ (or as a set theorist would call it, $V_\kappa$).  So, a small $\infty$-category is just an $\infty$-category that is an element of $U(\kappa)$.

Concretely, up to isomorphism, a small $\infty$-category is just an $\infty$-category $X$ such that $X_n$ is a set of cardinality less than $\kappa$ for each $n$.

Comment: Ah, so that supposes the definition of "size of a simplicial set"="max of |X_n|" ? Also, in proposition 5.1.4.2, as part of the statement, he refers " $C'$ is $\kappa$-small $\infty$ category. In which case, is the $\kappa$ here distinct?

Comment: addendum: fundamentally I am confused what it means to say something "is an element of $U(\kappa)$" i.e., how did it translate to your last statement.

Comment: It doesn't suppose anything.  A simplicial set is quite literally a set (just as everything is a set in axiomatic set theory).  So when I say something is an element of $U(\kappa)$, I mean that in the most literal sense possible.

Comment: There are various essentially equivalent ways you might define a simplicial set as a set, but one natural one is to say it is a pair $(X_{ob},X_{mor})$ where $X_{ob}$ is a function on the set of nonempty finite ordinals and $X_{mor}$ is a function on the set of order-preserving maps between nonempty finite ordinals.  (Here to avoid technical issues, a "function" is just a set of ordered pairs and does not include a codomain.)

Comment: The point is though that a Grothendieck universe is closed under all reasonable operations you could care about that don't involve going all the way up to the cardinal $\kappa$.  So, if $X_n$ is in $U(\kappa)$ for each $n$, then the simplicial set $(X_{ob},X_{mor})$ is automatically also in $U(\kappa)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey The converse strikes me as a bit nontrivial, and in particular I've never seen anyone explicitly state it, let alone prove it. But it may actually be trivial, I suppose-ah, never mind, it follows from the heuristic/definition of a universe being closed under any small operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this resolves my confusion.